# Ansible template: add section if a value is set to true

Tags: ansible, jinja2

In my Ansible `defaults.yml`, I have this:

```yaml
plugins:
  - name:  myfirstplugin
    install: true
  - name: ....
    install: true
  # etc...
```

I have a task that deploys a template. I would like a section to be added in this template if `myfirstplugin` is set to be installed (`install: true`)

So in my template I would need something like:

```
{% if plugins.name.['myfirstplugin'].install is true %}
text to be added if true
{% endif %}
```

How can I write this correctly?

Answer (score 3):

`plugins` is a list of plugin objects containing a `name` and `install` attributes.

The first thing is to select in the plugin list only the objects that match your criteria being `name == 'myfirstplugin'`. This can be achieved with the [`selectattr` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#selectattr)

The previous operation returns a list. In your case it should only contain one element. So we get the first object in the list with the [`first` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#first)

Then we only have to read the value of the `install` attribute wich should contain a boolean. To make sure this does not fire errors at all, we add two extra securities:

1. In case all of the above did not return an object (e.g. the plugin name is not in the list in case you decide to make this dynamic...), we use the [`default` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#default) to set the value to `false`
2. In case the field was parsed as text (e.g `"false"`), we cast it to a boolean with the [`bool` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#id8) so that it is interpreted correctly.

The final result for you jinja2 template is:

```
{% if (plugins | selectattr('name', '==', 'myfirstplugin') | first).install | default(false) | bool %}
text to be added if true
{% endif %}
```

Here is an all-in-one MCVE playbook based on the above example:

```yaml
 ---
 - hosts: localhost
   gather_facts: false

   vars:
     plugins:
       - name: toto
         install: true
       - name: titi
         install: false
       - name: tete
         install: true

   tasks:
     - name: shall we install plugin ?
       debug:
         msg: |-
           examining plugin {{ item }}:
           {% if (plugins | selectattr('name', '==', item) | first).install | default(false) | bool %}
           Include plugin
           {% endif %}
       loop: "{{ (plugins | map(attribute='name') | list)  + ['idontexist'] }}"
```

Which gives:

```sh
$ ansible-playbook test.yml 

PLAY [localhost] ********************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [shall we install plugin ?] ****************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=toto) => {
    "msg": "examining plugin toto:\nInclude plugin\n"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=titi) => {
    "msg": "examining plugin titi:\n"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=tete) => {
    "msg": "examining plugin tete:\nInclude plugin\n"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=idontexist) => {
    "msg": "examining plugin idontexist:\n"
}

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Answer (score 1):

First, let's see what these yaml variables will will become in terms of data structure. In your case, `plugins` will look like:

```
plugins = [{"name": "firstplugin, "install": true}, {"install": true, "name": "secondplugin"}]
```

What is the problem with this?

This is a list of dictionaries, so if you want to refer each individual plugin by name in template, you have to write a complex loop to iterate over all elements and find dictionary which has specific `name` and then again check for `install` attribute.
Good thing is, YAML lists are ordered so you can just refer them by index.

e.g. for firstplugin

```
{% if plugins[0].install %}
text to be added if true
{% endif %}
```

This will work, but it is not the best looking code and someone just reading the template will have to check variables to see what this is about.

So, I would suggest simplifying variable structure to:

```
plugins:
  firstplugin:
    install: true
  secondplugin:
    install: true
```

In terms of actual data sructure, this resemble to:

```
plugins = { "firstplugin": {"install": true}, "secondplugin": {"install": true} }
```

Now, referring to specific plugin and its attributes will become straightforward:

```
{% if plugins.firstplugin.install %}
text to be added if true
{% endif %}
```